# How to know, if h1 tag is working in SEO

Tags: php, html, seo

I am using h1 tag in my PHP home page.
Regardless of how i used my h1 tag, is there a standard way for knowing how SEOs (like google) behave with it and if they accept and grab h1 tag or not?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The processing and ranking algorithm of the SE's are not public, so we just can guess by try.

By the way, google released a document about how to build your website, which mentions the importance of the H1 tag:

http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Page 20.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a standard way for knowing how SEOs (like google) behave with it and if they are accept and grab h1 tag or not?

SE robots are not standardized in any way, so there cannot be a standard way for knowing what you would like to know.

One could assume because of semantics in a document that texts tagged with the `<h1>` element are important, as well as those within the `<title>` value.

But in the end of the search results you can not say in advance if this will play a role for your site or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well dear there are dozens of factors which help you to optimize your website or web-pages. and Header tags (h1,h2..) is just one of them, so if you truly wanted to optimize your web-pages please make sure that webpage must content with the below best & valuable ranking factors in that.

- Unique Title relevant to the content of webpage
- Snippets description which describe whole details in short of webpage
- Unique & proper formatted content
- Heading tag (H1) with the most relevant keyword to the webpage, try
  to place in upper portion of the page
- Bold content which is more relevant & valuable within content
- Well optimize Images Footer links 7.Recommend related content

Can find more SEO updates on my Google+ Profile https://plus.google.com/115326789223681674036